# Target an element with its id from component

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, dom

I would like to implement something similar to this in angular 4.

```
$('dataBlock').empty();
```

How would I access a DOM element with it's id from component? When I tried the following, I'm getting a error saying `Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`

```
<div id="dataBlock"></div>
```

component.ts

```
@ViewChild('dataBlock') block: ElementRef;

getGraphdata(){
    **code to get data and implement a graph**
    this.dataBlock.nativeElement.empty();
}
```

Comment: Use `#dataBlock` instead of `id="dataBlock"`. If you need to use the `id`, try `document.getElementById("dataBlock").empty()`.

Comment: ok, when I'm trying this two ways, I'm getting the following errors:  this. block.nativeElement.empty is not a function, Property 'empty' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

Comment: Try `.innerHTML = ""` instead of `.empty()`.

Comment: Yes, this works perfect. But Even if I use $('datablock').empty(); in component it's working fine. Why do we not consider using jquery selector directly

Comment: It works but that is not the way to do things in Angular. Instead of accessing element with their `id` or using jQuery, you should use [template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-). [This page](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) of the documentation shows how things works in Angular templates.

Comment: ok, got it. Thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome. :-)

Comment: Could you post your answer rather than in comments? So that it will be helpful if anyone like me need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard Javascript method to get the element by its `id`:

```
document.getElementById("dataBlock").innerHTML = "";
```

---

In Angular however, the preferred way to refer to an element is with a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-):

```
<div #dataBlock></div>
<button (click)="dataBlock.innerHTML = ''">Clear content</button>
```

That variable also allows to access the element in code with the help of `@ViewChild`:

```
@ViewChild("dataBlock") block: ElementRef;

clearContent() {
  this.block.nativeElement.innerHTML = "";
}
```